# Holomorphic function which is injective

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic in the upper half plane $\{\operatorname{Im}  z> 0\}$. Suppose that $\operatorname{Im} f'(z)> 0$ for all $z$ in the half plane. Show that $f$ is 1-to-1.

Comment: Let $z_0$ be a point on the upper half plane and $z$ be some other point. Connect $z$ and $z_0$ by a curve $\gamma$. How can I relate $z$, $z_0$, the derivative of $f$ (I need to use this, since that's what I'm given control over) and something involving $\gamma$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $z,w$ in the upper half plane with $z\ne w$, we have:
$$\frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}=\int_0^1f'(z+t(w-z))dt.\tag{1}$$
Since $\mathrm{Im}\,f'>0$, the imaginary part of the right hand side is positive, which implies $f(z)\ne f(w)$.

Comment: Way to go, +1...

Comment: @julien: Thanks!